# Hand waving during candle lighting

Tags: minhag, shabbat, sources-mekorot, women, candle-lighting

There seems to be a ubiquitous minhag for women to wave their arms around when they light candles, let's say for shabbos. I don't mean covering their eyes with their hands I mean waving around in the air beforehand. [Here's a video](https://youtu.be/RqZSfEtAVmk?t=47) in case you aren't familiar.

What is the source or reason for this minhag? How old is it? I'm hoping for textual sources.

Note: I read in Rabbi Reisman's book [Pathways of the Prophets](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422608937.html) that he looked into it and couldn't find any source or reason for it. I'm hoping the community here will have more success.

Comment: Are you distinguishing hand waving from using their hands to cover the flames? Because covering the flame is old and has a very specific halakhic rationale.

Comment: @DoubleAA yes I'll clarify.

Comment: Ok, just realize it's originally covering the flame not covering the eyes. Covering the eyes is just a more practical way to cover the flame: you are covering the entire world including the flame, relatively speaking.

Comment: I heard a while ago that it's a means of "taking in the holiness of Shabbat". I.e., the waving motion is inwards towards one's body as if one is taking in the light and beauty of Shabbat. I heard this a long time ago from, I believe, an aunt. I can't say where she got this idea from, but, from what I surmise, she believed in this, and it worked for her.

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/674406/jewish/Why-Do-Women-Wave-Their-Hands-over-the-Shabbat-Candles.htm see editor's note also https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/229/Q4/ source to 1718

Comment: @DanF looks like exact dup. I tried searching and didn't find anything...

Comment: @robev Hint: Google is a far better searcher than this site is. You can post a "complaint" on meta, but, I think the problem is more with Stack Exchange than Mi Yodeya.